# Column in Calendar says its used by content type, but its not!

Tags: content-type, calendar, column

I have created a custom content type called Vacation for a calendar list. When I look at the list settings page in the columns section, I find a column called Comments which indicates it is used in the Vacation content type.

when I click into the Vacation content type settings page, the Comments column is not listed in the column section.  Also, when I attempt to create a new calendar item there is no Comments section on the properties window.

Finally, Vacation is the only content type in this calendar.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Calendars are weird in that it uses a field with an internal of Comments but has a display name of Description. A lot of the calendar fields are this way, their internal field names differ from their display names.

Comment: very strange. so in the library settings the column will be called Comments and in the content type settings the column will be called Description?